# Setting Maximum Zoom Level kGMSMaxZoomLevel for Google Maps for iOS SDK

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying out the iOS Google Maps SDK and notice in GMSCameraPosition.h header file there is reference to kGMSMaxZoomLevel to set the maximum zoom level allowed. I'd like to be able to set this but when #defining a value for that in the implementation, XCode states that there are duplicate symbols when doing so, so won't compile. Can someone point me in the right direction for setting the Minimum and Maximum zoom levels using this new SDK?
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `kGMSMaxZoomLevel` is the maximum value which the SDK supports, ie which you can set when creating a `GMSCameraPosition`. You can't change its value, to make maps stop at a different zoom level.

You could maybe try listening for `[mapView:didChangeCameraPosition:]`, and then if the camera position is more zoomed in than you'd like, move it back out again. I haven't tried this, so I'm not sure if it would work. It might stutter a bit - ie the user will zoom a bit past the max, you'll set it back, then the user will zoom a bit past again, and so on.

Comment: That was perfect thank you. It isn't the nicest of UI but it does indeed snap back..
`    - (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position {
        if(position.zoom>9) {
            GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:position.targetAsCoordinate.latitude                                                                longitude:position.targetAsCoordinate.longitude                                                                  zoom:9];
            [self.mapView_ setCamera:camera];
        }
    }`

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old post, but just for the sake of completeness I am posting this.

Recent version of google maps SDK features `-setMinZoom:maxZoom:` which should serve your purpose.

Reference [link here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view#ada28a79f9041805492062cc8da7b23f2).

Comment: 4 Swift 3 like this: mapView.setMinZoom(6.0, maxZoom: 20).

Answer (score 0):

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {

    if position.zoom < 10 {

        let latitude = mapView.camera.target.latitude
        let longitude = mapView.camera.target.longitude

        let mapCamera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, zoom: 10)
        mapView.camera = mapCamera

    }
}
```